# How can I split a string by dealing using substring with regex with white spaces in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, split, whitespace

I have a string in Python with the value 'I take $80 from you and give you $ 100.00 back.'. Notice the difference between the two monetary values here. There is no white space between the '$' symbol and value in '$80' but there is a space between '$' and value in '$ 100'.

And I want to return a list which looks like ['$80', '$100.00'] or ['$80', '$ 100.00']. How can I achieve this using Python? I have tried this code which returns the list ['$80', '$100']:

```
>>> text = 'I take $80 from you and give you $ 100 back.'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\$\s*\d+', text)
['$80', '$ 100']
```

Comment: I dont understand how the output you get differs from what you expect ...

Comment: Just append `(?:\.\d+)?` to the regex. See https://ideone.com/FbddVs

Comment: there is no 100.00 in the `text` so im not sure why the `.00` would be part of the expected output

Comment: @not_speshal i dont think OP is actually struggling with the space ... im honestly not sure what the OP is struggling with

Comment: @JoranBeasley - The whole first paragraph of the question explains the space. I have no idea what they need either

Comment: @not_speshal and yet you can see in their actual output and regex they are capturing the space fine ... at a guess OP did not write original regex and for whatever reason thinks the space is problematic when it does not appear to be (at least to me)

Comment: @JoranBeasley - Agreed. Your first comment is on point - the actual output matches expected output lol

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(?:\.\d+)?` in addition to above regex pattern to match one or zero occurrence at last for the values from decimal point.

```py
>>> re.findall('\$\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?', text)
['$80', '$ 100']
```

Comment: Thanks @ThePyGuy for your response. I have one more doubt in this thread when the number is in the thousands. If I try the following code with a thousand number having commas in between, it looks like: – 

``` 
>> text = 'I take $80 from you and give you $ 1,000.00 back.'
>>> import re

>>> re.findall('\$\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?', text)

['$80', '$ 1']

```

Is there any way I can get rid of the commas using regex or get the entire amount i.e. $ 1000?

Comment: **regex** solution always depends on what the data looks like, previously,  your  data had only integer numbers i.e. `I take $80 from you and give you $ 100 back.`, so proposed solution had regex `'\$\s*\d+`, then you said there can be floating point numbers as well, so the regex changed to `\$\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?`, now you are saying it can have comma as well, that means the  regex needs to be modified to capture comma separated numbers as well.

Comment: You can try something similar to: `re.findall('\$\s*\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?', text)` for the text `'I take $80 from you and give you $ 1,000.00 back.' `

Comment: Also, Looking at your profile, you haven't accepted answers in any of the question you have asked. Please click on `✓` icon appearing on an answer that works for you, to accept that answer as the solution to your question so that it no longer appears in unanswered queue.